# CoCreateInstance() never returns

Tags: c++, c, com

I have a DLL in which I need to call CoCreateInstance().  In Dllmain(), I created a new thread to run my function do_stuff().  CoCreateInstance() is called in do_stuff(), as shown below.

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    ...
    switch(fdwReason) {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)do_stuff, NULL, 0, NULL);
            ...
            break;
        ...
    }
    ...
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI do_stuff(void) {
    ...
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(rclsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, riid, ppv);
        ...
```

However, CoCreateInstance() hangs and never returns. I have tried using the MULTITHREADED option as well, but to no avail. Any feedback or ideas is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Also, from the horse's mouth: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305723

Answer (score 1):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1688290/492336)

> You shouldn't be doing any API calls, especially for things like
>   creating threads or windows, from DLLMain.