# Embedding prolog engine in a dll

Tags: c++, dll, prolog, mingw, swi-prolog

I've been working on a C++ application that embeds a prolog reasoning engine lately and, as stated in the title, I am now trying to generate a DLL instead of an executable so I can use it in another project. Since I am new to DLL development, I thought I could start with a small example. I have 3 files:

- `likes.pl`: sample prolog file defining the predicate likes/2
- `likes.cpp`: defining the function `get_food()` that calls `PlQuery` and return the results in a `std::string`
- `food.cpp`: using the DLL to list all kinds of food that Sam likes

So my first try was the following:

```
swipl-ld -shared -dll -o likes -goal true likes.cpp likes.pl -DLIKES_EXPORTS -v
g++ -o food.exe -s food.cpp -L. -llikes -I. -L"c:/program files (x86)/swipl/lib" -lswipl -I"c:/program files (x86)/swipl/include"
```

First of all, let me point out that when `get_food()` only returns a string without any call to prolog, this works fine. However, after two days of investigation, I can't figure out how to get the DLL to call prolog. I think there are two things I am possibly doing wrong, maybe both: the PlEngine intialization and the saved state.

I've tried both calling PlEngine in `get_food()` and in `food.cpp` `main()` function, same result. So for now I am sticking to the first option since I am more interested in having everything done in the DLL. I see here ([Embedding SWI-Prolog in a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785922/embedding-swi-prolog-in-a-dll)) that it can later be done in the `DllMain` but also that it is not recommended. What is the best way to do it? Should I give food.exe as`argv[0]` or something else (libswipl.dll? a saved state?)

Secondly, I noticed that one difference when using swipl-ld to generate a DLL instead of an EXE is that it ommits the lines:

```
swipl.exe -f none -F none -g true -t"consult(['likes.pl']),qsave_program('pltmp-4228.exe',[goal=true,toplevel=prolog,init_file=none])"
cat pltmp-4228.exe >> food.exe
```

So I tried to do it manually, replacing the random name by "mystate.exe" and using the Win32 `copy /b` command to append it to food.exe. This makes food.exe a toplevel console where I can test `likes/2`. Is it because the Dll doesn't have any `main()`? Anyway, this is the furthest I could get for now and I guess there were a few things to change in the `qsave_program/2` second argument. I tried replacing `toplevel=prolog` with `stand_alone=true`. By the way, the command example given at the end of (http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%272.10%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/compilation.html%27%29%29) doesn't generate any file at all. Anyway, I can't figure out if and how exactly I have to do this either.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! In case somebody needs the answer someday:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    char* av[50];
    av[0] = (char*)"food.exe";
    av[1] = (char*)"-x";
    av[2] = (char*)"mystate.exe";
    if(!PL_initialise(3, av))
        cout << "NO init\n" ;
    else
        cout << "OK init\n" ;
    cout <<  get_food() ;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
swipl --goal=true --stand_alone=true -o mystate -c likes.pl
swipl-ld -shared -dll -o likes -goal true likes.cpp likes.pl -DLIKES_EXPORTS -v
g++ -o food.exe food.cpp -L"c:/program files (x86)/swipl/lib" -lswipl -I"c:/program files (x86)/swipl/include" -L. -llikes -I.
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, as this is not really a precise answer to your problem, just a report about my experience on the topic.

I've been working on [pqConsole](https://github.com/CapelliC/pqConsole), a DLL that introduces Qt bindings via the C++ interface.

pqConsole, while still in development, has so far found its way in [swipl-win](http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/packages/swipl-win.git), and I had the joy to work together with Jan Wielemaker making this little big step for Prolog audience widening.

I would suggest to build your DLL with G++, to get binary compatibility, and release SWI-Prolog component(s) as-is.

If you like Qt, you can use QtCreator for interface design, see for instance [fdqueens](https://github.com/CapelliC/fdqueens).
There you can also see how I used to embed .pl in Qt project *resources*, to have more control about the application (users can't mess with the Prolog logic that's *required* from other parts) and over the release (no .pl to add, just the executable/DLL).

HTH

Comment: > I would suggest to build your DLL with G++, to get binary compatibility, and release SWI-Prolog component(s) as-is.

I'm sorry but I don't understand what you exactly mean here. Would there only be some C++ code in my DLL ? Then how would my program be able to use all the predicates defined in my prolog code ? 
What I need is a way to get an API calling some logic. I am sure there's a way to do it properly and easily (once you know what arguments to use) in swi-prolog...