# C++11 deferred "thread" creation (i.e., specify thread function but do not wait physical thread to be created)

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++11

My goal is what i asked in title where i want caller thread does not wait the child thread to be physically created and resumed when using std::thread ctor with a thread function (non void ctors)

My problem hits (in Windows) when I try to create an std::thread object with a thread function during a DLL load.
It is a problem because (as far as i beleive)
- Thread constructor tries to create a physical thread
- Ctor somehow (and unluckly for me) waits the physical trhread to resume (go live)
- Unfortunately, Win API does not allow the threads to resume within the LoadLibrary call if they are created during that function call.
- So I have a dead-lock: LoadLibrary creates a thread, it waits for it to resume, Windows does not let it to resume.

I can invent some solutions to that problem (by having a distinct thread not using std::thread which will be constructing additional threads (std::threads), but i then miss the whole point of using "only" std::thread for my threading needs :-) ).
However, it would be best if std::thread be told not to wait for physical thread to resume if it is constructed with a thread function (or lambda or whatever).
Is there a way of doing this or I should go for work-arounds?
thanks

- **One more case when one would need the same**
  In the fast path, I may create (lazyly) an std::thread object, post some tasks to it (many tasks potentiall), and go-on (in the fast path) without getting delayed! I may not care when the child thread really physically gets created and resumes.
  It would be pitty if one cannot lazly have physical threads created in such fast-pathes or during DllMain etc.

Comment: Are you creating the thread inside the DllMain?

Comment: Actually i am creating the thread in a DLL-wide global C++ object ctor. I beleive CRT initializations doing these kinds of staff are called from DllMain

Comment: They are called before `DllMain` is even entered I would say. Honestly, I'd suggest you to delay the creation of the thread till after `DllMain` returns. Export an `initialize()` function from your dll and require loading modules to call it (after having loaded the dll). The `initialize()` function would then create the objects that start the thread.

Comment: Could `std::async` help you in any way?

Comment: I already have such initializer (and cleanup) functions exported. If i will not find a direct solution, i will do it as you suggested. Thanks Andy.

Comment: std::async has the potential with the same problem as the spec says that sometimes it executes the function within the caller thread's context!

Comment: You should read about `DllMain`. You should NOT be doing anything besides the simple initialization in it.

Comment: What i needed and asked was actually what you are suggesting: Trigger the thread creation but do not wait. Before trying to switch std::thread, i could easily do this using _beginthreadex where the caller thread did not get blocked till the requested thread gets created!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the *way* you are creating the thread, but rather in the fact itself that you are creating a thread while the DLL is being loaded. While calls to `CreateThread` may be safe (as long as no waiting operations are performed by the launched thread), [it is in general a bad idea to create threads during `DllMain`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/27/63401.aspx).

What you should do here is to export an initializer function and require loading modules to invoke it after your DLL has been loaded. The initializer function would then instantiate all the required objects and create all the necessary threads.

Also see [this Q&A on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688290/creating-a-thread-in-dllmain).

Comment: THen may I assume that there are no way of doing what i needed: If a non-empty std::thread is to be created, it necessarily blocks the caller till the physical thread is really created and resumes? Pitty...

Comment: @mami: Yes, there is no way because the C++11 Standard specifies that the completion of the construction of the `std::thread` must synchronize with the start of the thread function (§ 30.3.1.2/5).