# Initializing COM Security Failed

Tags: c++, com

Im trying to initialize COM Security from DLL, but im getting error `800401f0`. Im using mostly a standart approach,

Code:

---

```
 HRESULT hres;

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    // Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
    // Set general COM security levels --------------------------

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
        );
```

and it works pretty well if i run it from my app.exe, but problem is that im running it inside .DLL that actually is an functions extender for Main.exe(That i dont have access - source or any).

And this whole code i use to get machine data like - BIOS Version, via `IWbemClassObject` & `IEnumWbemClassObject`, so i was wondering what are the easier/simpler ways of solving it, or retriving the hardware Data ( Like `BIOSVersion` `Win32_BIOS SerialNumber` `Win32_VideoController Name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error `800401f0` means that CoInitialize has not been called for current thread, but your code snippet makes it look like it is.

I guess that the code shown in the snippet is either from your own app.exe, or if it is from the dll then these two calls are not made on the same thread.

This means that you need to initialize COM inside the dll, but this is not as straightforward as it may look, as you don't control the application threads -  initializing COM inside a dll should be avoided unless you can ensure that you controll the thread on which the COM calls are executed.

A possible solution is to [create a worker thread for COM calls where you can initialize COM according to your requirements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2004/05/12/things-you-shouldnt-do-part-2-dlls-cant-ever-call-coinitialize-on-the-applications-thread/).

Comment: alright, now its a bit clearlier, so am i suppose to make an call for `DLLMain DLLDLL_THREAD_ATTACH` ? `BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
 DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
 LPVOID lpReserved
 )`  `case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH: SetCOMInit()` - that what worker thread would be ?

Comment: I am not sure if I understood correctly, but you can't just initialize COM in DllMain call. You need to create a thread, which is actually a tricky business: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688290/creating-a-thread-in-dllmain

Comment: damn thats truly seems to hard, maybe there are some better ways to get HWID info, to acctualy BIND the program on the machine that is executing it.