# Why does the window never show up, although all required functions are present?

Tags: c++, windows, forms, winapi

I have been trying to make a universal DLL to where I can inject it into a process & a window would pop up. I have all required functions such as WinMain (I named mine Initiate and called it manually), DllWindowProcedure, and DllMain. However, after compilation, there is one warning and no errors - I believe it is a logical error. If you spot any issues, or anything I can improve, please let me know!

Warning:

> 1>Main.cpp(43): warning C4060: switch statement contains no 'case' or 'default' labels

Code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

HINSTANCE InjectedModuleHandle;

LRESULT CALLBACK DllWindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

DWORD WINAPI DllThreadProcedure(void * Data)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)"Welcome to Flames v1.1!", (LPCSTR)"Startup Message", NULL);
    MSG Messages;
    WNDCLASSEX WindowClass;
    WindowClass.hInstance = InjectedModuleHandle;
    WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"DllWindowClass";
    WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = DllWindowProcedure;
    WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WindowClass.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    WindowClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    WindowClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    WindowClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)RGB(255, 255, 255);
    RegisterClassEx(&WindowClass);
    HWND Window = CreateWindowEx(0, L"DllWindowClass", L"Flames v1.1 - By XenoSaga3000", (WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX), 200, 200, 500, 450, FindWindow(NULL, L"ROBLOX"), CreateMenu(), InjectedModuleHandle, NULL);
    ShowWindow(Window, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    while (GetMessage(&Messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Messages);
        DispatchMessage(&Messages);
    };
    return 1;
};

LRESULT CALLBACK DllWindowProcedure(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParameter, LPARAM LParameter)
{
    switch (Message)
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(WParameter)
            {
                //Check for commands here.
            };
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParameter, LParameter);
    };
    return 0;
};

bool APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE DllInstance, DWORD Reason, LPVOID Reserved)
{
    if(Reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        InjectedModuleHandle = DllInstance;
        CreateThread(0, NULL, DllThreadProcedure, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    };
    return TRUE;
};
```

Comment: Try something simpler first, like showing dialog box, to see if your DLL is loaded properly at all.

Comment: I know for a fact the DLL was injected..

Comment: `switch(WParameter){};` - This is why you are getting a warning.

Comment: I realized that I just wanted to rule everything out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can look at this [blog](https://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/c-creating-a-window-from-a-dll/) for an example for your case.

One of the differences is that it uses DllMain's provided `HINSTANCE` as the instance handle for the window class.  `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` returns the instance handle of the calling process instead of the DLL.

Note that Windows API calls like CreateThread from DllMain are not recommended, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688290/creating-a-thread-in-dllmain).

Comment: @Levi Branch, apparently there are different opinions on that. Did the blog sample fix your issue?

Comment: @TonPlooij: The wording of [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx) (*"should never [...] call `CreateThread`"*) is the source of confusion. What this really is trying to say is, that synchronization inside DllMain can lead to deadlocks. And when you do create a thread, you almost always implement some sort of synchronization. Creating a thread itself really is fine, since you can safely assume that *kernel32.dll* is always mapped into a running process.

Comment: @Ton Pooij I haven't tried it yet but I suspect it will.

Comment: @TonPlooij I've rewritten my code based off the example with still no avail. Updated the thread.

Comment: Also I forgot to mention, but the message box shows & the window doesn't if that helps narrow the issue. @TonPlooij

Comment: Your code does not show a RegisterClassEx for your windows class. You should also check in the FindWindow for the parent succeeds and provides a correct handle. I suggest to follow the sample code as close a possible.

Comment: Also, your WNDCLASSEX omit CS_GLOBALCLASS.

Comment: Also your wchar_t * PString = reinterpret_cast<wchar_t*>(LpParameter); is wrong because you pass ANSI string.

Comment: Updated code again. Still no avail, only the message box works.

Comment: I must note I did not follow the FindWindow advice because the DLL is meant for that specific process & I plan on having specific instructions for using it. Also, I was unable to do the CS_GLOBALCLASS because I have no idea where to find it.

Comment: If you want your dll for only one process, omit CS_GLOBALCLASS is fine. But how you test your dll?

Comment: @user2120666: `CS_GLOBALCLASS` makes available a registered class to all **modules** in a process. You seem to imply that this class style would somehow allow a window class to be registered system-wide. This is not the case.

Comment: @user2120666 I inject it into RobloxPlayerBeta.exe, the actual target.

Comment: Anyways, my problem is that I have no idea what CS_GLOBALCLASS is or how to implement it, so my DLL will never be fixed :(

Comment: WindowClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS | CS_GLOBALCLASS;