# Unable to call method in managed dll after loading CLR. Why?

Tags: c++, .net, dll, clr, inject

I have met some issues when trying to inject a dll into a process. I am quite new at the topic but am familiar with C# so reading and understand the syntax of C++ wasnt that unfamiliar and i understand it for the most part.

What i am trying is only for learning, and i am trying this with simple applications like notepad.exe and calc.exe.

Project setup:

- WPF application - To pick the process i want to tinker with and inject the unmanaged dll.
- CppDLL.dll - Unmanaged dll to load CLR, managed dll and call method on managed dll.
- SharpDLL.dll - Managed dll.

**(wpf) c# of interest**

```
dllToInject = fileDialog.FileName;
Process targetProcess = Process.GetProcessById(processToInject.ID);
var dllInjector = DllInjector.GetInstance;
DllInjectionResult injectResult;
if ((injectResult = dllInjector.Inject(processToInject.Name,dllToInject)) == DllInjectionResult.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success");
} else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + injectResult.ToString());
}
```

The unmanaged dll is successfully injected when not trying to load clr and managed dll as shown below.

[image: Screenshot showing successful injection of unmanaged dll to notepad process]

But when i try to load CLR and managed dll it fails.

**CppDLL.dll** dllmain.cpp :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <metahost.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "mscoree.lib")

#import "mscorlib.tlb" raw_interfaces_only \
    high_property_prefixes("_get","_put","_putref") \
    rename("ReportEvent", "InteropServices_ReportEvent")

void LoadDotNet()
{
  HRESULT hr;
  ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost = NULL;
  ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
  ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrRuntimeHost = NULL;

  hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));
  hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
  hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeHost));
  hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();

  DWORD pReturnValue;
  hr = pClrRuntimeHost->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
    L"C:\\Users\\DanHovedPC\\Desktop\\inject\\SharpDLL.dll",
    L"SharpDLL.Injected",
    L"Start",
    L"Hello from .NET",
    &pReturnValue);

  pMetaHost->Release();
  pRuntimeInfo->Release();
  pClrRuntimeHost->Release();
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
           )
{
  switch (ul_reason_for_call)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Hi!", L"From cpp DLL", NULL);
    //LoadDotNet();
  case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
  case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
  case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
    break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

**SharpDLL.dll** Injected.cs

```
using System.Windows;
namespace SharpDLL
{
    class Injected
    {
        public static int Start(string arg)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(arg);
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In CppDLL.dll if i uncomment the function and comment the messagebox it fails. The SharpDLL.dll does not get injected. And when i try to close notepad the process still shows up in Process Explorer.

I have looked at the process in [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) beforehand and the clr.dll is not loaded by default, but it gets loaded when the function runs. Maybe it could be the .NET version? I am running Windows 10 x64.

**Update**

The code runs until i try to actually start the runtime

```
void LoadDotNet()
{
  HRESULT hr;
  ICLRMetaHost *pMetaHost = NULL;
  ICLRRuntimeInfo *pRuntimeInfo = NULL;
  ICLRRuntimeHost *pClrRuntimeHost = NULL;

  hr = CLRCreateInstance(CLSID_CLRMetaHost, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pMetaHost));
  hr = pMetaHost->GetRuntime(L"v4.0.30319", IID_PPV_ARGS(&pRuntimeInfo));
  hr = pRuntimeInfo->GetInterface(CLSID_CLRRuntimeHost,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&pClrRuntimeHost));

  // start runtime
  MessageBox(NULL, L"Runs up to here...", L"DEBUG", NULL);
  hr = pClrRuntimeHost->Start();
  MessageBox(NULL,(LPCWSTR)GetLastError(),L"DEBUG",NULL);
  pMetaHost->Release();
  pRuntimeInfo->Release();
  pClrRuntimeHost->Release();
}
```

The first messagebox shows.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was that code within DllMain must not access the CLR.

> Code within DllMain must not access the CLR. This means that DllMain should make no calls to managed functions, directly or indirectly; no managed code should be declared or implemented in DllMain; and no garbage collection or automatic library loading should take place within DllMain.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173266.aspx

When creating a new thread the code runs successfully

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
  DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
  LPVOID lpReserved
  )
{
  switch (ul_reason_for_call)
  {
  case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    //printf("DLL Loaded!");
    CreateThread(NULL, 0,
      (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadDotNet, NULL, 0, NULL);
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

And from reading a [comment on another question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688290/creating-a-thread-in-dllmain#comment-2166738) CreateThread should be safe in this particular case.