# Debugging .DLL Injection Issue - Breakpoint On Supposedly Executing Code Not Being Hit

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, dll, dll-injection

I have written a program (.DLL) which is to be injected into process.exe.

DLL injector code:

```
Bool InjectDll(DWORD pID, const char* dllPath) {
    Proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    if (!Proc)
    {
        return false;
    }
    void* LoadLibAddr = (void*)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA");
    void* RemoteString = (void*)VirtualAllocEx(Proc, NULL, strlen(dllPath), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(Proc, (LPVOID)RemoteString, dllPath, strlen(dllPath), NULL);
    HANDLE ret = CreateRemoteThread(Proc, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibAddr, (LPVOID)RemoteString, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL);
    if (ret) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

DllMain() function of .DLL to be injected:

```
#include <Windows.h>

extern void vMain();

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
    )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&vMain, 0, 0, 0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

vMain:

```
void vMain() {
    CreateConsole();        
    std::cout << "vMain() has executed!\n";
}
```

The .DLL to be injected works fine when I compile it in visual studio, but when I compile in QT Creator, `vMain()` never gets executed. The injector, .DLL, and target process are all 32-bit. So I have tried to debug the target process by making the .DLL injector call `CreateRemoteThread()` with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag, that way I can set a breakpoint on `LoadLibraryA()`, resume the thread, step through execution from the breakpoint, and view the return value. However, my breakpoint on `LoadLibraryA()` isn't being hit.

So I debugged the .DLL injector application to make sure that the remote thread was being created. I confirmed that it is by calling `GetThreadID()` on the return value of `CreateRemoteThread()`, outputting it, and viewing that thread in the threadlist of the target process:

[image: ThreadList]

Keep in mind the thread is still suspended. Upon further inspection, EIP points to the first instruction in `_RtlUserThreadStart()`. I set a breakpoint on this instruction. I then resume the suspended thread by calling `ResumeThread()` from my .DLL injector program. The breakpoint is not hit.

It is noteworthy that the target application does not have any anti-breakpoint mechanism, and breakpoints have worked fine for me apart from this instance.

So how can I figure out what the issue is? Is there a reason my breakpoints are not being hit? Is there a better way to debug the problem?

Comment: Is `dllPath` a full path? If not then are you sure that it can be reached when run from Qt Creator?

Answer (score 0):

When doing console output from inside a DLL, you may need to redirect `stdout` to the console:

```
// AllocConsole() instead of CreateConsole()
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout); // <====
std::cout << "vMain() has executed!\n";
```

Additionally, It's not a good idea to create threads inside `DllMain()` and here's why:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040127-00/?p=40873/

Related question:

- [Creating a thread in DllMain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688290/creating-a-thread-in-dllmain)

I remember I've had some trouble with it in the past and I stopped doing such things as creating threads / windows inside `DllMain()`, as recommended.

Still, there are cases where it works, but I wouldn't trust it.

That being said, if the above doesn't work, try to call your `vMain()` directly without a thread and see what happens.